# getting my Document's parent sharepoint Folder

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, event-handlers, document, folder

I have a sharepoint document library containing documents and folders (the folders are newly introduced as a new content type derived from folder) and I'm having an event reciever on document added only to my folders.
So to recover the parent folder of my newly added document I tried to write this way but it doesn't seem to work well :

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);

    //getting the item (document) newly added to my content type folder
    SPListItem myItem = properties.ListItem;
    //getting the folder containing my doc
    SPFolder myFolder = myItem.File.ParentFolder;
    //other code on my SPFolder
}
```

Comment: While adding the document, have you identified and select the folder? Added the document inside your desired folder?

Comment: see I'm making an event handler, so I'm not concerned with the adding ,I'm just dectecting my added document and I'm trying to retrieve its parent folder's name

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a check if `myItem.File` is null, so your code will crash when a folder is added, but besides from that it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SPFolder parentFolder = null;
if (spListItem.Folder != null)
{
    parentFolder = spListItem.Folder.ParentFolder;
}
else if (spListItem.File != null)
{
    parentFolder = spListItem.File.ParentFolder;
}
else
{
    SPFile spFile = spListItem.Web.GetFile(spListItem.Url);
    if (spFile != null)
        parentFolder = spFile.ParentFolder;
}
```